# How validate an object using @Valid in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm working on a Spring Boot project and I'm trying to validate some fields from an object.

Actually I have an API which accepts parameters. I know I can use `@Valid` into API declaration like this:

```java
@GetMapping(value="/...")
Object myMethod(@RequestParam(value="name") @Size(min = 3) String name)
```

But I don't want to validate there. I have a "filter" object to validate the values, so I expect something like:

Controller file

```java
@override
public Object myMethod(String name){
  @Valid Filter filter = new Filter(name)
}
```

And filter is not an entity, only a class with validations tags:

```java
public class Filter

  @Size(min = 3)
  private String name;

  public Filter(name){
    this.name = name;
  }

  // getters and setters
```

So the idea is to use `@Valid` creating the object and throws an exception if any validation is not successfull. Is this possible?

I have found multiple solutions to validate query params, body requests and so on, but not about validate a single object created using `new`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see that's not possible. The closest solution to your case would be to manually validate the entity with:

```java
@Autowired
private Validator validator;
```

and then validating your object like so:

```java
@Override
public Object myMethod(String name){
    Filter filter = new Filter(name);
    validator.validate(filter);
}
```

Comment: I've tested this but it doesn't throw an exception. Have I missed something?

Comment: It's not going to throw an exception. It returns a set of the constraint violations if there are any, otherwise it'll just return an empty collection.

Answer (score 1):

`@Valid` has following annotation targets:

- METHOD
- FIELD
- CONSTRUCTOR
- PARAMETER
- TYPE_USE

As it does not have `LOCAL_VARIABLE` target it's not possible to use it for variable validation inside method body.

You don't receive compilation error due to `TYPE_USE` which is mainly used as supportive annotation for type checking